# É possível colocar uma imagem dentro da barra de progresso?

Tags: html5, css3, bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

Gostaria de saber se é possivel colocar uma imagem dentro da barra de progresso do bootstrap, enquanto a barra vai caminhando, logo a frente dela vai tipo um carrinho pequeno. Isso seria possível?

Barra de progresso:

```
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 80%">
    <span class="sr-only">80% Complete (danger)</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim é possível vc tem que trabalhar com a classe **`.progress-bar-striped`** e fazendo um override dos valores default do Bootstrap.

Para deixar apenas um imagem no final da barra onde ela vai completando basta colocar o CSS assim, **Repare que o *Background* está alinhado a direita da barra verde, com isso ela acompanho o progresso da barra.**

> Veja funcionando no Snippet abaixo:

```
.progress-bar-striped {
    background-image: url(http://www.gmstatic.com/templates/default/images/ok_icon.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top right;
    background-size: 20px;
    background-color: rgb(232, 255, 232);
}
```

---

Se quiser uma imagem ocupando a Barra indeita.

```
.progress-bar-striped {
    background-image: url(http://www.almowazi.com/Images/Titles/News_ar.png); /* sua imagem */
    background-repeat: no-repeat; /* imagem não repete dentro da barra */
    background-position: top left; /* imagem inicia a esquerda */
    background-size: 100%; /* imagem fica com 100% da largura da barra completada */
    background-color: black; /* cor de fundo caso a imagem não carregue */
}
```

**OBS:** A imagem vai ficar sempre com a largura total da barra completada. Veja que a `<div class="progress-bar... style="width: 80%">` está em 80% e a imagem vai completar toda a barra, e quando for 100% a imagem vai ***"espichar"*** até completar 100% e se for 10% ela vai fica ***"comprimida"*** dentro dos 10% do tamanho da barra... *Então escolha uma imagem que possa ser comprimida na horizontal sem problemas maiores.*

***Snipper com a imagem no final da barra a direita.***

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<style>
    body {
        width: 90%;
        margin: 2rem auto 0;
    }
    .progress-bar-striped {
        background-image: url(http://www.gmstatic.com/templates/default/images/ok_icon.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: top right;
        background-size: 20px;
        background-color: rgb(232, 255, 232);
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 80%">
            <span class="sr-only">80% Complete (success)</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muito bom! Mas teria como mostrar apenas uma imagem? sem ser essas todas, mostrar só uma e mostrar ela no final?

Comment: @Maria editei minha resposta resposta para ficar da forma que vc queria, olha se te atende. Deixei todos os comentários no CSS `.progress-bar-striped` que está no início da resposta. Qq coisa me fala.

Comment: Mas tipo, eu nao quero que a imagem se expanda, tende? eu quero só uma, mas ela pequeno andando de acordo com o progresso. ex.: se ta 100% a imagem vai estar la no final, mas pequena

Comment: @Maria Agora acho que está do jeito que vc queria, Executo e Snippet para ver.

Comment: Exatamente isso! Muito obrigada :D

Comment: @Maria use o `background-size: 20px;` no meu exemplo eu coloquei 20px, mas vc pode colocar o tamanho que quiser, inclusive em %, tipo 10%. Ai vai da sua imagem, e da largura que vc vai querer na barra. Por padão a barra tem justamente 20px da height. []´s

Comment: Eu vi. Obrigada!!